# TIdMessage.SaveToStream does not save properly

Tags: delphi, indy10

While trying to transfer an Imap TIdMessage from a Thread to the MainThread, I discovered that saving it to Stream and then loading it back does not work.

```
Log('Msg.MessageParts.Count='+Msg.MessageParts.Count.ToString,d_4); // 3 parts
AStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
MSG.SaveToStream(AStream);

MSG := TIdMessage.Create(nil);
MSG.LoadFromStream(ASTream);
Log('After Load: Msg.MessageParts.Count='+Msg.MessageParts.Count.ToString,d_4);// Zero parts
```

Is there something I can do about this? I need a copy of the entire TIdMessage.

Comment: Are you seeking `AStream.Position` back to `0` before calling `Msg.LoadFromStream()`? Also, why not just transfer the whole `TIdMessage` object as-is instead of a copy of its data via `TMemoryStream`?

Comment: Oh no.. I made the same mistake again! I am going to hang it on the wall: Put the bloody Stream back to zero! Regarding transfering the actual TIdMessage from the Thread where its was created to the main thread: I got exceptions trying to manipulate MessageParts afterwards. But this may also have been caused by me not setting Streams to zero. .. Thanks Remy.

Comment: Nothing in TIdMessage is tied to the thread that creates it. So you probably just have a bug in your code that tries to use TIdMessage across threads. Feel free to post a new question about that, if you want.

Comment: You are right, it was an internal bug. I just stuffed up the resetting of the Stream counter in the attempt to resolve the original issue I had..

Answer (score 2):

As [Remy Lebeau commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77160988/tidmessage-savetostream-does-not-save-properly/77161543#comment136027851_77160988), I needed to set `AStream.Position` back to zero before calling `Msg.LoadFromStream()`.